# Running Symfony DIC smoke tests in SF3.4 and above

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4, symfony4

Fetching services from the DI-container is an integral part of the smoke tests in my test suites. The following test makes for instance sure that there are no problems with the construction of services registered in the container and that these services do not take too much time for construction.

```
private const DEFAULT_TRESHOLD = 30;

public function testServicesLoadInTime()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    /**
     * Add serviceid as key, possible values:
     * - false: Skip test for this service
     * - integer value: Custom responsetime
     */
    $customCriteria = [
        // See: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/192
        'monolog.activation_strategy.not_found' => false,
        'monolog.handler.fingers_crossed.error_level_activation_strategy' => false,
        // Should not be used directly (Factories will inject other parameters)
        'liip_imagine.binary.loader.prototype.filesystem' => false,
        // Services that are allowed to load longer (Only for CLI tasks like workers)
        'assetic.asset_manager' => 1000,
    ];

    foreach ($client->getContainer()->getServiceIds() as $id) {
        if (isset($customCriteria[$id]) && $customCriteria[$id] === false) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            $startedAt = microtime(true);
            $service = $client->getContainer()->get($id);
            $elapsed = (microtime(true) - $startedAt) * 1000;
            $this->assertNotNull($service);
            $treshold = $customCriteria[$id] ?? self::DEFAULT_TRESHOLD;
            $this->assertLessThan($treshold, $elapsed, sprintf(
                'Service %s loaded in %d ms which is more than the %d ms threshold',
                $id, $elapsed, $treshold
            ));
        } catch (InactiveScopeException $e) {
            // Noop
        } catch (\Throwable $ex) {
            $this->fail(sprintf("Fetching service %s failed: %s", $id, $ex->getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

However. Version 4 of Symfony will make [services private by default](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.4.md). The upcoming version 3.4 will trigger a deprecation warning when fetching services from the service container using the `get()` method when the service has not been marked public.

This left me wondering whether there is a way to keep this smoke test running without creating a public service which takes all services as constructor arguments, which is with almost 1000 services in the container off course not a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

**This approach [with all its pros/cons is described in this post with code examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/#2-in-symfony-4-1-standalone-or-symfony-3-4-4-0).**

---

The best solution to access private services is to add **a Compiler Pass that makes all services public for tests**.

### 1. Update Kernel

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
+use Symplify\PackageBuilder\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\PublicForTestsCompilerPass;

 final class AppKernel extends Kernel
 {
     protected function build(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
     {
         $containerBuilder->addCompilerPass('...');
+        $containerBuilder->addCompilerPass(new PublicForTestsCompilerPass());
     }
 }
```

### 2. Require or create own Compiler Pass

Where `PublicForTestsCompilerPass` looks like:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

final class PublicForTestsCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
    {
        if (! $this->isPHPUnit()) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($containerBuilder->getDefinitions() as $definition) {
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }

        foreach ($containerBuilder->getAliases() as $definition) {
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }
    }

    private function isPHPUnit(): bool
    {
        // defined by PHPUnit
        return defined('PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL') || defined('__PHPUNIT_PHAR__');
    }
}
```

To use this class, just add the package by:

```
composer require symplify/package-builder
```

But of course, the better way is to use own class, that meets your needs (you migt Behat for tests etc.).

**Then all your tests will keep working as expected!**

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom configuration for your services just for the test environment where you set everything public. Alternatively you could alias the services you want to test (in your test environment).

The thing is that you will alter how the container is compiled per environment and therefore the metrics in terms of how long it took to retrieve the service is probably not really useful anymore. The good news is, that it wasn't that particularly useful to begin with, because there is nothing you can really do about it being slow and with opcache it should not be an issue anyway.

For having a smoke test that makes sure the service is available making them public in the test environment is fine (at leat for me) or alternatively you can do smoke tests through the UI using WebTestCase. By making sure that your routes are accessible you indirectly ensure that there are no 500 errors due to inaccessible/misconfigured services.

When it comes to functional tests of services from the container I think there is no way around making them public or aliasing them (only in test if necessary).

Comment: Quick addition: Testing the availability of services through the UI using WebTestCase is also more useful when you want to set loading time constraints, because the page load speed is probably more useful as a metric. With that you can profile and check what exactly causes the performance issue and fix the concrete problem instead of doing vague and questionable micro optimizations somewhere in the service container. ;)

Comment: Offtopic: I agree that smoke testing routes is important as well. However, checking for the load time of a service makes it possible to detect places where to much work is done in the constructor or the constructor of a dependency. This can be an incentive to lazy load the service. It made me discover for instance an unwanted blocking curl call deep down in the dependency tree that was triggered on every page load but hardly ever needed.

Comment: For now I fixed it by loading a different environment where all services are public by default. I'm getting the client with: ``$client = static::createClient(['environment' => 'test']);`` And my test.yml environment config contains: ``services:
    _defaults: { public: true }``

Comment: Small addition to the above: As Alister Bulman points out, services that are explicitly marked private do need to be added to the ignore list since there is no way to check whether a service is private or not.

Comment: Heavy services that need to be lazy loaded is actually a good counter example to my initial assumption. I still think this can be discovered through application profiling after a bigger smoke test fails using a dedicated performance testing tool like XHprof or blackfire. Having it as part of the test suite might have little benefit after the issue is solved, at least when service instantiation is not touched that often, and keeping the tests causes a bloated suite with longer runtime, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a **very** similar smoke-test (which has allowed me to find issues before now) - but without the time-taken element. My list of 'private' services has been getting longer, and without some form of `->getContainer()->isPrivate($id)` will just continue to do so.

There will still be some public services, that I create, or from the framework, so I'm happy to just add them to the exclude list as they appear.